# How to create custom directives in Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm currently documenting a rest API written in Python. All the project's documentation is created using Sphinx, and for the REST API I would like to create some special directives. For instance, let's say I have this resource defined:

```
@resource("/user/<email>", method="GET")
def user_details (email):
    """ Returns detailed information about a user account.

    :resource GET: /user/<email>
    :query_param a_param: Some kind of query param.
    """
    # Do stuff and return user details
```

That's basically how the documentation currently looks. I would like to be able to create a directive for Sphinx that formats one or more of those `:query_param ...:` just like it does with regular `:param:`.

I have found how to make roles, but they only work inline, not for blocks of data.

**How** should I go about making this?

Comment: You may want to ask this on the [Sphinx Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/sphinx-dev).  Someone there might be more capable of answering the question.  Off-hand, I'm not sure how documentation blocks are treated.  You can certainly [create extensions in Sphinx/docutils](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/extensions.html), but I'm not sure how docstring parsing fits into the Sphinx/docutils model.

Comment: The answer probably involves using a [GroupedField](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/src/1f3a2749df39/sphinx/util/docfields.py#cl-74) in your extension though.

Answer (score 15):

Sphinx can be extended with custom directives via "[Sphinx Extensions](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/extensions.html)". That is, you will need to implement a Sphinx extension providing the `query_param` custom directive, and add this extension to your Sphinx project.

Sphinx documentation provides [a tutorial](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/extdev/index.html#dev-extensions) on implementing extensions, in which they implement a custom directive indeed.

Reference:

http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/extensions.html

http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/extdev/index.html#dev-extensions