# Substitution in a file name with reStructuredText (Sphinx)?

Tags: python-sphinx, substitution, restructuredtext

I want to create several files from a single template, which differ only by a variable name. For example :

(file1.rst):

```
.. |variable| replace:: 1
.. include template.rst
```

(template.rst) :

```
Variable |variable|
=====================

Image
-------

.. image:: ./images/|variable|-image.png
```

where of course I have an image called "./images/1-image.png". The substitution of "|variable|" by "1" works well in the title, but not in the image file name, and at compilation I get :

```
WARNING: image file not readable: ./images/|variable|-image.png
```

How can I get reST to make the substitution in the variable name too? (if this changes anything,  am using Sphinx).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two problems here: a substitution problem, and a parsing order problem.

For the first problem, the *substitution reference* `|variable|` cannot have adjacent characters (besides whitespace or maybe _ for hyperlinking) or else it won't parse as a substitution reference, so you need to escape it:

```
./images/\ |variable|\ -image.png
```

However, the second problem is waiting around the corner. While I'm not certain of the details, it seems reST is unable to parse substitutions inside other directives. I think it first parses the image directive, which puts it in the document tree and thus out of reach of the substitution mechanism. Similarly, I don't think it's possible to use a substitution to insert content intended to be parsed (e.g. `` .. |img1| replace::`.. image:: images/1-image.png` ``). This is all speculative based on some tests and my incomplete comprehension of the [official documentation](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html), so someone more knowledgeable can correct what I've said here.

I think you're aware of the actual image substitution directive (as opposed to text substitution), but I don't think it attains the generality you're aiming for (you'll still need a separate directive for the image as from the |variable|), but in any case it looks like this:

```
.. |img1| image:: images/1-image.png
```

Since you're using Sphinx, you can try creating your own directive extension (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12527783/custom-directives-in-sphinx) for information), but it won't solve the substitutions-inside-markup problem.

Comment: So, in short you are telling me that there is no simple way to do this... I really don't see how to bypass this parsing order problem. That's too bad, as it restricts the templating possibilities of reST. I eventually decided to do the substitution using a Python script that duplicates the reST code. It's ugly but it works fine. Anyway, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a custom directive in this case as Sphinx doesn't allow you to substitute image paths. You can change Sphinx figure directive as follows and use it instead of the image directive.

```py
from typing import Any, Dict, List, Tuple
from typing import cast

from docutils import nodes
from docutils.nodes import Node, make_id, system_message
from docutils.parsers.rst import directives
from docutils.parsers.rst.directives import images, html, tables

from sphinx import addnodes
from sphinx.directives import optional_int
from sphinx.domains.math import MathDomain
from sphinx.util.docutils import SphinxDirective
from sphinx.util.nodes import set_source_info

if False:
    # For type annotation
    from sphinx.application import Sphinx


class CustomFigure(images.Figure):
    """The figure directive which applies `:name:` option to the figure node
    instead of the image node.
    """

    def run(self) -> List[Node]:
        name = self.options.pop('name', None)
        path = self.arguments[0]  #path = ./images/variable-image.png
        #replace 'variable' from th.e given value 
        self.argument[0] = path.replace("variable", "string substitution")
        result = super().run()
        if len(result) == 2 or isinstance(result[0], nodes.system_message):
            return result

        assert len(result) == 1
        figure_node = cast(nodes.figure, result[0])
        if name:
            # set ``name`` to figure_node if given
            self.options['name'] = name
            self.add_name(figure_node)

        # copy lineno from image node
        if figure_node.line is None and len(figure_node) == 2:
            caption = cast(nodes.caption, figure_node[1])
            figure_node.line = caption.line

        return [figure_node]


def setup(app: "Sphinx") -> Dict[str, Any]:
    directives.register_directive('figure', Figure)

    return {
        'version': 'builtin',
        'parallel_read_safe': True,
        'parallel_write_safe': True,
    }
```

You can add this CustomFigure.py directive in the conf.py of the project and use the customfigure directive across Sphinx project instead of the Image directive. Refer http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/index.html to add a custom directive to your Sphinx project.