# reStructuredText substitution inside table-csv on sphinx

Tags: csv, python-sphinx, substitution, restructuredtext

I'm trying to make a substitution on the file loaded by the table-csv directive on Sphinx.
My idea was to do something like:

```
.. csv-table:: My CSV Table
:header: "Column 1", "Column 2"
:file: some/path/|branch|/to/file_|version|.csv
```

It seems to replace neither branch nor version.

I tried to add white spaces around the variables I want to substitute as on the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20513972/restructured-text-sphinx-substitution-in-a-file-name)

I also tried (without success) to create a variable with the full path outside, on conf.py as follows.

```
rst_prolog = f"""    
.. |my_csv_file| replace:: ../path/{git_branch}/to/file_{version}.csv
"""
```

To then import it as:

```
.. csv-table:: My CSV Table
    :header: "Column 1", "Column 2"
    :file: | my_csv_file |
```

Is there any way (without using custom directives if possible) to achieve this?

Thanks beforehand!

Comment: [Substitutions](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#directives-for-substitution-definitions) can be used only to replace text and inline elements, not within directives or their options.

Answer (score 1):

CSV tables treat data as-is. They are even not picked up by gettext to be translated.

I recommend you to use list-table or grid (painted) table. It both works with `|subtitution|` and are localizable.

```
.. |project-name| replace:: SuperSecretProject

.. list-table::
   :header-rows: 1
   :widths: auto

   * - Parameter
     - Description

   * - ``UserId``
     - ID of allowed user that can enter |project-name|.
```

Comment: Oh, that looks like a solution to me. Thanks!